# Replace part of an href using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, youtube

I have an 'iframe' which loads up a page. On this page it has multiple links which lead to external pages, I want to replace part of the 'href' so that it links to 'Youtube' instead. For example a link on on the page looks like this.

`http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=yQGAwrtB65A&t=`

I want to replace

`http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=`

with this

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`

so that it will end up as

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQGAwrtB65A&t=`

I have tried some jquery examples but the link just remains the same. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you could post what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried `$('a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=', 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
    });`

Comment: @Sabre so it should replace it. You are doing something wrong somewhere else, maybe not calling code at right time. How do you call this code?

Comment: I used `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @Sabre so provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue (if you can) because all answers you'll see here will be quite the same code as you are already using...

Comment: As you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKwSB/  And of course you have checked your console for any error, right?!

Comment: This is the link to my code http://jsfiddle.net/Hck4a/

Comment: @Sabre Ok i see, cross domain iframe, you cannot access content... Proxify it server side is the only one solution i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use jQuery, try this:

```
var url = "http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=yQGAwrtB65A&t=";
url = url.replace("http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=","http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have multiple links which needs `http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=` replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with both javascript and php

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//Array with urls
$url = array("http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=XXXXXXXX1","http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=XXXXXXXXX2");
//Loop through urls
foreach($url as $u){
    //Dump new URLS to new array
    $new_url[] = str_replace("http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php? id=","http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", $u);
}
//Dump all new URLS
var_dump($new_url)
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//Array with urls
var url = Array("http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=XXXXXXXX1","http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=XXXXXXXXX2");
//Declare new_url array
var new_url = Array();

//Loop through all urls
for(i=0; i<url.length; i++){
   //Push new URLS to new array
   new_url.push(url[i].replace("http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php? id=","http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="); 
}
//alert all new urls
alert(new_url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Hck4a/ it should help explain my issue.

Comment: I still dont understand what you whant to achive.

Comment: @PhilipG he wants to modify content of a cross domain iframe... Typically an unclear question from the beginning

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear but I want to replace all the `http://ytchannelembed.info/video.php?id=` with `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` automatically as I cant change each specific link as the web page receives new videos on a regular basis.

Comment: @Sabre but are these links inside a cross domain iframe like in your jsfiddle or not??? I hope you can answer this question more clearly. The answer should be **yes** or **no**

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm afraid it is. I am a complete noob to iframe. I thought you could access information when the client page was loaded. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Sabre that's ok, like i said, you have to proxify it server side then you can access content but need a little more work